# Trying to add audio element within HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, mp3

Hello I am working on a school project that would add audio to html for a webpage. I have everything typed up and whereas I have the physical controls, actually two places in error, but am getting no audio. I need to add the video element but I'm sure once I have this figured out that will be relatively simple. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ericWood.css">
  <script src=http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js ></script>
  <script src="ericWood.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
         height:1150px;
         width:1280px;
    }

    #advertising {
         background:olive;
         width:20%;
         height:1000px;
         float:right;
    }

    #sidebar {
         height:1000px;
    }

    #footer {
         height:50px;
         width:1280px;
         background:black;
         text-align:center;
         clear:both;
    }

    p {
         font-size: 22pt;
    }

    #content {
         text-align:center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <header> 
  <div id="header" id="png"><span id="someId"><h1>Eric Thomas Wood</h1></span></div>
      <h3>Today is <span id = "dtField"></span>
      </h3>
  </header>
<div id="sidebar"><h2>About me</h2>
    <nav>
        <details>
            <summary>Page Content</summary>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <p>Please click <a href="dioPage2.html">Nikki</a> to learn about my lovely wife Nikki</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>Please click <a href="dioPage3.html">Rachel and Bekah</a> to learn about my awesome children</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>Please click <a href="dioPage4.html">Nick and Savanna</a> to learn about my amazing stepchildren</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>Please click <a href="dioPage4.html">Bubba and Lexi</a> to learn about our pets</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>Please click <a href="dioPage4.html">More Eric</a> to for more about me</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </details>
    </nav>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <p>My name is Eric Wood! I am first and formost a family man, a husband and father of four wonderful children. As with most 
    people I am sure, I have evolved and adapted to life's challenges in my 37 short years. I am a musician at heart as I played 
    trombone for over ten years and was quite good at it. Music is what I first went to college for until I managed to earn a
    position with the post office and started a family. Fast forward a failed marriage, two wonderful girls, and losing my career
    job, I am remarried with an additional two stepchildren, an amazing wife, and I am enrolled at University of Phoenix about to
    complete my IT degree. Life has been hard at times but the future looks amazing.</p>
</div>
<div id="advertising">
    <audio id = "audioTrack">
        <source src = "howBlueCanYouGet.mp3" type = "audio/mpeg">
        <source src = "howBlueCanYouGet.ogg" type = "audio/ogg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
    <div id = "controls">
        <progress></progress>
        <div id = "buttons" style = "padding:5px;">
            <a href = "#" id = "play">Play</a>
            <a href = "#" id = "pause">Pause</a>
            <a href = "#" id = "stop">Stop</a>
        </div>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" id="setLocation"/>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $("audio").on('timeupdate', function(evt){
        var duration = evt.target.duration;
        var current = evt.target.currentTime;
    $('progress').val(current/duration);
});

    $('#play').click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    $("audio")[0].play();
});

    $('#pause').click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    $("audio")[0].pause();
});

    $('#stop').click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    $("audio")[0].currentTime = 0;
    $("audio")[0].pause();
});

    $('#setLocation').change(function(evt) {
        var val = $(evt.target).val();
        var duration = $("audio")[0].duration;
        var location = duration*(parseInt(val)/100);
    $("audio")[0].currentTime = location;
    $("audio")[0].play();
});
</script>
<div id="footer"><strong>Copyright &copy 2016</strong></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't know what the issue is as I'm strictly staying directly with any video tutorials and readings from the class. It should be working but is not. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please put your code into a https://jsfiddle.net/  so we can execute what you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

maybe your browser don't support audio/video
[Browser Support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLPSK.jpg)

Comment: I am fairly certain it does as I was just using mp3 with chrome.

Answer (score 1):

When you have set an id for an element, it might be a good idea to use them.

```
<audio id="audioTrack">
```

To use the element above with the id, change:

```
$("audio")[0].play();
```

to:

```
$("#audioTrack")[0].play();
```

You can also use the audio element like this to get an actual player with HTML5, if you don't want to reinvent the wheel with your own timeline thing:

```
<audio controls>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/62uv4auo/1/ (edit: forgot to update the fiddle)

Comment: I considered just using <audio controls> but wanted to jazz it up for the project. Does it have cross browser functionality for all browsers?

Comment: I have done exactly what you said and even tried the code in the fiddle but I am getting no audio from the page within chrome.

Comment: Do you get any sound in Chrome at all?
What OS are you running?

Comment: You can use the following link to try out <audio> and different formats in your browser:
http://hpr.dogphilosophy.net/test/index.php

You can also use this site for checking cross browser functionality of any element: http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio

Comment: I tried the link and get audio but I do not when loading the page on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what my issue was. There was no closing tag for the source tag. It should look like this.

```
<source src = "howBlueCanYouGet.mp3" type = "audio/mpeg" />
```